# Matrix inequality on positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \succeq 0$ and $B \succeq 0$ be two semi-positive definte matrices. 
Assume $\{a_{1}, \cdots, a_{n}\}$ is the set of normalized orthogonal basises of matrix $(A-B)$. Let's we define
$$ P\triangleq(a_{1}, \ldots,a_{m}), \qquad Q\triangleq(a_{m+{1}},\ldots, a_{n}),$$
in which $(a_{1}, \ldots,a_{m})$ correspnds to $(A-B)$'s nonnegative eigen-values, and $(a_{m+{1}},\ldots, a_{n})$ correspnds to $(A-B)$'s negative eigen-values.

Please proof or disprove

$$\begin{pmatrix}P^{T}BP & P^{T}AQ \\ Q^{T}A
P& Q^{T}AQ  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}P^{T}BP & P^{T}BQ \\ Q^{T}BP& Q^{T}AQ 
\end{pmatrix} \succeq 0$$

Comment: Please share also what you already did on the subject and how far you got.

Comment: I cannot proof its result. I just simulate some matrices that match this result

Answer (score 1):

Disproving by a randomly generated example:

```
>> A = [5 6; 6 8];
>> B = [2 -1; -1 5];
>> [V D] = eig(A - B);
>> d = diag(D);
>> P = V(:,find(d >= 0));
>> Q = V(:,find(d < 0));
>> M = [P' * B * P, P' * A * Q; Q' * A * P, Q' * A * Q];
>> eig(M)

ans =

    3.3028
   -0.3028
```